# Retrieve the Value of An Integer Variable

Tags: c++, variables, integer

This is probably easily figured out, but I can't find a solution anywhere, for some reason. Perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing. And maybe it's in some beginner tutorial I haven't watched.

Anyway, I was wondering how to retrieve the value of an integer variable in C++? I know you can use `cin.getline()` for string variables, but I received an error message when I attempted that with an integer variable (and rightfully so, I know it was wrong, but I was looking for a solution).

My project is a Win32 console application. What I'm trying to do is ask a user to input a number, stored in the variable `n`. Then I take the value of `n` and perform various math functions with it. In my header file, I have `string`, `windows`, `iostream`, `stdio`, `math`, and `fstream`. Do I need to add another library?

**EDIT:**

```
cout << "TEST SINE";
cout << "\nPlease enter a number.\n\n";
cin >> n;
break;
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use. Is this all I need to do? If so, how do I incorporate the variable so I can test it using sin, cos, and tan?

Yet again, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: use float or double instead of int

Comment: I just realized that, thank you! I think I'm going to change it to a double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is the problem with this?

```
cin>>n;
```

For math functions, float or double would be better option.

```
int main()
{
   double number;
   double result;

   cout<<"Enter a number:"<<endl;
   cin>>number;

   result = sin (number);  //if you consider number is in radians
   //result = sin(number*3.14159265/180.0) //if you consider number is in degrees    

   cout<<result;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably nothing, but you should explain that `n` is initialized with `int n;`.

Comment: I'm using that, but whenever I retrieve a string variable, I have to use cin.getline(). I figured it would be the same way with integers. Perhaps I'm wrong, I'm just a bit confused on this issue (as I said, I feel stupid). I'm going to update the post with my code.

Comment: `cin.getline()` reads until it hits a newline character.  `cin >> n` reads until it sees whitespace.  So if the user enters `10 20 30` you would have to do `cin >> n` three times to retrieve all the input.  However, `cin.getline()` would retrieve the entire string.  Along this same train of thought, if you were to define `std:string s` and then do `cin >> s` then you would only get `"10"`.

Comment: @milkypostman: It doesn't read until whitespace per se, but until the input no longer makes sense for what it's reading *or* until it gets whitespace. So you can still read the integer 5 if the input was "5asdasd".

Comment: Yes, I'm going to change it to double. This was a stupid question, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an integer, you can use:

```
cin >> n;
```

but you had better have control of the input data if you want a robust application.

Perhaps a better idea would be to input it as a string as you already know how to do with `getline()`, then validate that the string consists of all numeric characters before calling a conversion function like `atoi()` or `strtol()`.

That way, you get robust input plus the data types you want.

But, if you want to use trigonometric functions, you're probably better off working with doubles, with `atof()`, rather than integers.

---

Here's a sample program to get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    char s[256];

    // Get and check line.

    cout << "Enter angle in degrees: ";
    cin.getline(s,100);
    for (char *ps = s; *ps != 0; ps++) {
        if (!isdigit (*ps)) {
            cout << "Not numeric" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Output string, float, sine and cosine (convert to radians first).

    float f = atof (s);
    cout << "String : '" << s << "'" << endl;
    cout << "Float  : " << f << endl;
    f = f * 3.141592653589 / 180.0;
    cout << "Sine   : " << fixed << sin (f) << endl;
    cout << "Cosine : " << fixed << cos (f) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs shown below:

```
Enter angle in degrees: 30
String : '30'
Float  : 30
Sine   : 0.500000
Cosine : 0.866025

Enter angle in degrees: 45
String : '45'
Float  : 45
Sine   : 0.707107
Cosine : 0.707107

Enter angle in degrees: 90
String : '90'
Float  : 90
Sine   : 1.000000
Cosine : -0.000000      (caused by floating point inaccuaracy).
```

Comment: Whoops, I meant to @ reply to you. You gave me an idea, but it says that the std namespace doesn't have a getline() function.

Comment: @Abluescarab: give that one a shot. I've modified it to make it simpler.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the trouble and the late reply!